# Ownership of objects created in Lead Conversion

Tags: standard-objects, lead-conversion, ownership

What are the rules of ownership when converting a lead? Who becomes the owner of the Opportunity, Account and Contact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you have different options.

**Creating a new Account, Contact, Opportunity**

When converting a lead into a new Account, Contact and Opportunity, all 3 records are created with the same owner, this defaults to the same owner as the Lead when you started your conversion. Upon conversion, you still get the possibility of changing the owner to someone else. By selecting another user in the lookup dialog. 
One thing to keep in mind is, if the Lead is owned by a Queue, you *must* define a Record owner, as Accounts and Contacts cannot be owned by Queues.

[image]

**Merging a Lead into an existing Account**

When converting a lead, and you choose to merge the lead in an existing account, by choosing an existing Account in the Account Name list, or by using the Lookup dialog, you will not change the existing Account data, thus the existing account owner doesn't change.
However, since you are creating a new Contact (and possibly) a new Opportunity in the account, that owner is still decided by the same Lookup dialog when converting a Lead as explained before.

[Documentation on the previous 2 methods](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/leads_convert.htm)

**Converting a Lead from Apex**
This is a bit different from the others, but in a sense, it's exactly the same. The only difference is that you can set the owner from apex by using the function `setOwnerId()` if you choose not to provide an ownerId, the same Owner is used as the lead (unless the owner of the lead is a queue, then an Owner must be defined, and the conversion will fail), and the same goes for converting from apex in an existing account, the account owner doesn't change, but the lead/opportunity does.

From the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_convertLead.htm):

> **setOwnerId** Specifies the ID of the person to own any newly created
>   account, contact, and opportunity. If the application does not specify
>   this value, the owner of the new object will be the owner of the lead.
>   This method is not applicable when merging with existing objects—if
>   setOwnerId is specified, the ownerId field is not overwritten in an
>   existing account or contact.